# Self hosted intranet for Employee Engagement communication and collaboration

Tags: chat, document-management, survey, self-hosted, forum

I'm doing a little research related to tools for internal use in medium/large company that allows communication and collaboration among its employees.

I need to build a solution (intranet) that **I could host in company's infrastructure (self hosted)** and can provide the following features:

- Chat. (Maybe something similar to slack/hipChat/etc.?)
- User profiles
- Forum where employees can submit questions or suggestions where others partners can give feedback, etc.
- Post surveys
- Document Repository / Sharing
- LMS, where employees could take courses or training
- CRM (I know this may not be for internal use)

As far I've seen, I'm 90% sure I won't find one unique tool that meets all these requirements listed, but I'd love to hear some suggestions about which tools I could get and integrate by implementing APIs, syncing users, etc.

*PS: It would be interesting to get tools that can be measured, for example to get in some way the grade of employee engagement, participation and so.*

Platform: ANY. As I'll have a new server just for this, I'll be able to install Windows, Debian or whatever needed to implement the tools

Comment: Any price tag (budget limit)? If non-free solutions are acceptable, would a subscription model (monthly/yearly fees) be acceptable as well?

Comment: first thing on my mind is a social network script like humhub: https://www.humhub.org/

Comment: It will be a budget limit @Izzy but depends on which solution I find...

Comment: Thanks @YoshiBotX for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the atlassian suite fits your needs :

[HipChat](https://www.atlassian.com/software/hipchat) : chat
[Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) : bug tracking / tasks for your employees + profiles.
[Confluence questions](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/questions) : QA
[Surveys for Confluence](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.adaptavist.confluence.survey/server/overview) / ServiceDesk 
[Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence) : is like a wiki, you can post pages / attachments
[LMS addon for Confluence](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.edubrite.confluence.plugins.gilly/cloud/overview) 
[CRM for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/ru.teamlead.jira.plugins.teamlead-crm-plugin-for-jira/server/overview)

Comment: Wow @daredevil ... sounds great... Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: basically you're buying, right ? :-)

Comment: I guess we won't have any other option @daredevil but we're still searching

Answer (score 1):

I think MS Sharepoint 365 service can do all of this, except to CRM maybe

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-service-description